# Multiple COUNT / GROUP BY statements return unexpected results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Querying a postgreSQL 9.4 db, I want to be able to see how often each customer is interacting with each employee based on previous orders. My aim is to retrieve data in the following format:

```
CUSTOMER     EMPLOYEE    INTERACTIONS   CUSTOMER_TOTAL
Customer1    EmployeeA             30               50
Customer1    EmployeeB             20               50
Customer2    EmployeeD              6               15
Customer2    EmployeeA              6               15
Customer2    EmployeeC              3               15
```

...where I have a separate record in the results for every combination of customer and employee (assuming at least one order has taken place between the two).

I want to include a column containing the number of orders between a customer and each individual employee (See column 3 above), and another column with the total number of orders for each customer overall (see column 4 above).

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT customer.name as Customer, employee.name as Employee, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN orders.employee_id = employee.id AND orders.customer_id = customer.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interactions,
  SUM(CASE WHEN orders.customer_id = customer.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Customer_Total

FROM tblcustomer customer
  JOIN tblorder orders ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
  LEFT JOIN tblemployee employee ON employee.id = orders.employee_id

GROUP BY customer.name, employee.name

ORDER BY Customer, Interactions DESC;
```

Which returned the following results:

```
CUSTOMER     EMPLOYEE    INTERACTIONS   CUSTOMER_TOTAL
Customer1    EmployeeA             30               30
Customer1    EmployeeB             20               20
Customer2    EmployeeD              6                6
Customer2    EmployeeA              6                6
Customer2    EmployeeC              3                3
```

All rows / columns appear as expected, except for the final column. Instead of a count of total orders for each customer, it has returned only the orders where the employee is also a match. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: CUSTOMER_TOTAL for Customer1 should be 50 & for Customer2 should be 15?

Comment: Yes, as per the example at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `LEFT JOIN` here:

```
SELECT customer.name as Customer,
       employee.name as Employee, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN orders.employee_id = employee.id AND
                       orders.customer_id = customer.id
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interactions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN orders.customer_id = customer.id
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Customer_Total
FROM tblcustomer customer
LEFT JOIN tblorder orders
    ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
LEFT JOIN tblemployee employee
    ON employee.id = orders.employee_id
GROUP BY customer.name,
         employee.name
ORDER BY Customer, 
         Interactions DESC;
```

My hunch is that your `INNER JOIN`s are filtering out records which would comprise the customer total.  By using `LEFT JOIN` you are retaining these records.

Comment: I've replaced my joins with `LEFT JOIN`, same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

One left join with tblEmployee would do the task. Inner join with tblEmployee will filter and get only those records which are number of orders between a customer and each individual employee.

```
   SELECT customer.name as Customer,
   employee.name as Employee, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN orders.employee_id = employee.id AND
                   orders.customer_id = customer.id
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Interactions,
   SUM(CASE WHEN orders.customer_id = customer.id
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Customer_Total
   FROM tblcustomer customer
   JOIN tblorder orders
   ON orders.customer_id = customer.id
   LEFT JOIN tblemployee employee
   ON employee.id = orders.employee_id
   GROUP BY customer.name,
     employee.name
   ORDER BY Customer, 
     Interactions DESC;
```

Comment: I've tried replacing my second inner join with `LEFT JOIN`, this did not affect the results. I have also tried replacing both joins with `LEFT JOIN` with no luck.